# Value greater than 0.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am working on an old version of rails 3.2. The column is a `string` and I need to validate that the value is `<= 0.1`. From the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#numericality) states "By default, it will match an optional sign followed by an integral or floating point number".

`validates :min_amount, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 0.1 }`

But even when I submit `0.5` it says it's not greater than or equal to `0.1`

Comment: Why is the column a string type?

Comment: Your problem is that it's a string type.  A string type will evaluate to zero against a floating point.  You would need to create a lambda that will convert it to a floating point and then do the comparison.

Comment: @Jordan that's a good question. This app has some serious issues that we are trying to address after taking it over. It's been one giant headache after another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, it should convert value to float automatically:

```
validates :min_amount, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 0.1, only_float: true }
```

Comment: Looks like this still throws the same error `* Min amount must be greater than or equal to 0.1`

Comment: Never mind, it's because the previous developer (who didn't know rails and didn't know what he was doing) added a `parse_as_integers` to this attribute. If his model wasn't 384 lines it would be easier to see that.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the string to a floating point decimal with `to_f`. Or make the column a floating point itself.